# FreeRTOS (Terminal to see the output STDIO)

Tags: freertos, stm32f4discovery

I am working on STMdiscovery board, i installed freertos on the board and made the LED blink successfully, now i want to output some printf statements on the some terminals, (i think freertos supports STDIO). Can anybody guide how to do this and some documents which would help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

How printf() works is a feature of the tools you are using, rather than FreeRTOS.  If you are using tools specifically provided for embedded development then they will provide options for directing the output of printf() - typically in that type of embedded system the output would be directed to a UART or UDP port, on the STM32 you can use ETM.

If you are using generic GCC tools then you will have a little more work to do to providing the output functions yourself.

However, you need to take a lot of care using printf() in a small multi-threaded system.  It is rarely thread safe, can take masses of stack, and the time taken to output characters can interrupt your application.

As you are using FreeRTOS, consider something like FreeRTOS+CLI instead: http://www.freertos.org/cli

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried working with gcc and was able to see the output using picocom on the terminal.

Is there a way to Fork the programs and and perform multitasking in FreeRTOS?